# Hablar contigo vs Hablarte vs Hablar con tú

Tags: selección-de-palabras, gramática

What's the difference in connotation between these three phrases? Are they all correct? I am trying to say `I want to talk to you.`

> Quiero hablarte.
>
> Quiero hablar contigo.
>
> Quiero hablar con tú.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference in the three phrases:

1.) The first is more direct.  In English, the translation is of course, `I want to speak to you

2.) The second is a bit personal.  It suggests that you have a discreet reason to be talking to this person.  It is the equivalent of `I want to speak with you`

3.) The third is not right, nor will it ever be.  Tú is a pronoun.  In English, without an context. the word `you` is pretty ambiguous and would be difficult to explain.

```
You grind the salt like this - passive
I see you - direct object
I made you a cake - indirect object
```

### I made this cake for you

This sentence has a preposition, and, in Spanish, `Tí` is the object of a preposition.  This isn't to say that `tí` should follow every preposition.

There are exceptions of prepositions that exemplify the use of `mí/tí`.

- A tí/mí
- Con tí/mí
- Sin tí/mí
- Para tí/mí
- De tí/mí
- Sobre tí/mí
- En tí/mí

http://users.ipfw.edu/jehle/courses/pronouns.htm

`Con tí` is pretty much never used, but it is 100% more correct than `Con tú`

`Contigo` is some kind of bastardized way of saying Con tí.  I do not know exactly why they even added -go to the end.

Answer (score 1):

The first two options are correct:

```
Quiero Hablarte

Quiero Hablar contigo
```

The third one is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

"Hablar con tú" is incorrect. Both `Quiero hablarte` and `Quiero hablar contigo` are correct, but there is a difference, due to the use of "te". You could use `Quiero hablar contigo` as it is, but you won't hear just `Quiero hablarte`, you'll hear as

> Quiero hablarte **de algo**

Since **te** is a pronominal particle that you are adding to a pronominal verb, and thus it will need a direct object.

Answer (score 0):

"Quiero hablarte" is all good, it translates to I wanna speak to/with you.
"Quiero hablar contigo" is exactly the same as above but maybe you can say it's in a more expanded way?

"Quiero hablar con tú" it's plain wrong, "contigo" is the correct one in this scenario.